# Google places Api in android Display all category?

Tags: android, google-places-api

ho to display all category in Google places API in android

this "**https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?blablabla&type=food**?" show for only food..
how to display all category in google places api

Answer (score 2):

Google does't have supported for all types of categories..
[Supported types link - click here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types)

If you want to search all types you have to use pipeline symbol(|) and type all that u wanted
[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?blablabla&type=food|bar|gym|casino|hotel|school|....](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?blablabla&type=food%7Cbar%7Cgym%7Ccasino%7Chotel%7Cschool)